# Entity Framework Generic Repository Query

Tags: c#, generics, frameworks, repository, entity

I have this function below, where I want to define T as a class. Is this possible. The IsActive and RecordStatusCode are in every model class.  Is it possible to query this way.  Thanks

```
    public IQueryable<T> GetActive()
    {
        return DbContext.Set<T>().Where(x => x.IsActive && x.RecordStatusCode == "A");
    }
```

Comment: Use an interface/base class.... this has been asked thousands of times

Comment: I have a base repo like this:  public interface IRepository<T> where T : class.  How do you add a base class to it.  What's the syntax. Thanks

Comment: `public IQueryable<T> GetActive() where T : BaseClass`

Comment: Since it's clear that you are just learning, I'd suggest strongly against creating a repository to hide EF. I was referring to what PoweredByOrange mentions

Comment: I have a working repo, not a newbie... What I'm trying to do is extend what I have already. so I can keep this logic that works. public interface IRepository<T> where T :  class .. and add something like public interface IRepository<T> where T :  class; <someother base class>    can you implement two classes

Comment: X.isACtive isn't property of T. T should be Interface having the property

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetActive()
    {
       var t = typeof(T);  
       var isActiveProperty = t.GetProperty("IsActive");
       var recordStatusCodeProperty=  t.GetProperty("RecordStatusCode");

     return DbContext.Set<T>().Where(x => (bool)isActiveProperty.GetValue(x, null) && recordStatusCodeProperty.GetValue(x, null).ToString() == "A");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was looking for.  Some type of reflection statement.  I'll give this a try.   Something like :  

 public IQueryable<T> GetActive()
        {
            return DbContext.Set<T>().Where(x => (bool)x.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive").GetValue("IsActive") && 
                                   (string)x.GetType().GetProperty("RecordStatusCode").GetValue("RecordStatusCode") == "A");
        }

Comment: Have a meeting.  The syntax is working so far (no errors). going to try it this afternoon thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks Houssem.  I gave it a try, but no luck.  I also tried the GetField method. got the following error on the controller :{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: Well Houssem,  I appreciate your help.  What I found out is that certain methods in reflections are not translatable into Linq. What's would need to do is query the data, convert it to a list, then perform reflection over that.  Painful.. But, thanks for the coding fun!   Here is a related article.      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028029/getvalue-linq-error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to why this will not work. Closing this post.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4593cc8-6e7f-41e4-a63f-bd148d396204/error-when-creating-an-object-query-in-a-generic-function?forum=adodotnetentityframework